# iptables ESTABLISHED,RELATED in combination with DNS rules

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, firewall, iptables

I'm reading Chapter 3 in "Cybersecurity for Small Networks" (Seth Enoka) and have added the following `iptables` rules in an Ubuntu 22.04.1 virtual machine:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Sep 30 12:58:31 2022
*filter
:INPUT DROP [454:44400]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [129:7740]
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Sep 30 12:58:31 2022
```

The VM runs a bridged adapter, with the host connected to a router. The book now claims that if output connections to 80/443 are wanted, additional rules are required:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I can however not confirm this claim, or only partially. When not using the above rules for 80/443, HTTP connections to IP addresses indeed time out. When using them with DNS, however, they are accepted:

```
$ curl ip.me
<ipv6 address given>
$ curl 212.102.35.236  # resolved by dig
<times out>
```

To me it seems that these HTTP requests are marked as RELATED, and thus implicitly allowed by the `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rules. Since the goal is to only allow certain ports and services, should this catch-all rule be removed in this case? Or is there a different solution?

Note: After applying the rules I've run `conntrack -F` to flush any existing connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To me it seems that these HTTP requests are marked as RELATED, and thus implicitly allowed by the RELATED,ESTABLISHED rules

This is not the real reason (iptables does not have a conntrack helper for DNS inspection), but one easy way to verify it is by splitting the rule into two separate `-m state` rules – one to allow RELATED and another for ESTABLISHED. Then you could comment out the RELATED rule (while keeping ESTABLISHED) and check whether the connection stops being allowed.

> ```
> $ curl ip.me
> <ipv6 address given>
> ```

This means the HTTP connection was established using IPv6, not IPv4, so it was not checked against any iptables rules in the first place – the IPv6 packets were checked against **ip6tables** rules, which you haven't defined yet so everything is still being allowed.

The tables and chains are completely separate for those two protocols, so on dual-stack machines you will need to manually duplicate the entire ruleset across both iptables and ip6tables.

(When doing so, you must change `-p icmp` to `-p ipv6-icmp` for the ip6tables version, and possibly add a new rule allowing DHCPv6 packets if your network uses it. Everything else is practically the same.)

---

One way to easily maintain dual-stack iptables rules is by using a hand-written .rules file as the "source" and avoiding any direct rule addition. The same .rules file can then be loaded by both `iptables-restore` and `ip6tables-restore`, with certain rules using the `-4` or `-6` options to make sure they're ignored by the "wrong" tool. For example, the rule that allows SSH from your local subnet would be written as `-A INPUT -4 -s 192.168.1.0/24 ...` and would have an accompanying "-6" rule that allows SSH from your IPv6 subnet as well.

Though I would recommend ferm or nftables instead – the former will automatically load a single ruleset into both, while the latter has native support for a combined v4/v6 "table inet" family. (It's quite likely that on latest Ubuntu all your iptables rules are actually being translated to nftables rules under the hood.)

Comment: Thank you for the fast and detailed explanation! ipv6 was indeed the problem.